# Solve following Separable Differential Equation. Explain is there any constant solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find a solution of $xy' = y^2- y$ that passes through indicated points :
$$a)\space (1,0), \space b) \space(0,0) \space c)\space (1/2 , 1/2) \space d)\space (2, 1/4)$$

Comment: Are you giving us an assignment?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: First of all thanks for explaining. But tell you what solving a differential equation is not a problem for me. Problem is that im not good at my english writing skills. After solving This DE i apply the points as IC when x=0 then y= 0 , then i got 0= 0 what does that mean??? What is the value of c in this case. And when i used the 2nd point (0,0) i got 0 = infinity or 0 = 0. For 3rd point i got c = 2  and for the last one i got c = -3/2 . Please explain what happens in 1st and 2nd point namely (0,1) and (0,0). Due to lack of writing skills i uploaded the entire question. Help me on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note :** It's always important to show some effort. This is not a homework solving site. Below I'll just elaborate on a partial answer to leave you with work to do.

First of all, you have to find a general solution, which you will use to apply the initial values given (the points) in order to conclude to a specific solution via constant calculation. Starting off :

$$xy' = y^2 - y \Leftrightarrow y' = \frac{y^2-y}{x} \Rightarrow \int \frac{y'}{y^2-y}dx=\int\frac{1}{x}dx $$

$$ \Leftrightarrow $$

$$\ln|-y(x)+1| - \ln|y(x)| = \ln|x| + c_1 \Leftrightarrow \ln\bigg|\frac{-y(x)+1}{y(x)}\bigg| = \ln|x| + c_1 $$

$$\Rightarrow \dots \Rightarrow$$

$$y(x) = \frac{1}{c_1x+1}$$

I left the steps in the calculations in-between for you to handle and figure out. Now, for the part of the points, you just have to express them as $(x_0,y(x_0))$ and apply them as $y(x_0) = y_0$ to find different values for $c_1$ each time. Finally, regarding the constant solution, what conclusion can you figure out by the elaboration of the points-part of the question ?

Comment: First of all thanks for explaining. But tell you what solving a differential equation is not a problem for me. Problem is that im not good at my english writing skills. After solving This DE i apply the points as IC when x=0 then y= 0 , then i got 0= 0 what does that mean??? What is the value of c in this case. And when i used the 2nd point (0,0) i got 0 = infinity or 0 = 0. For 3rd point i got c = 2  and for the last one i got c = -3/2 . Please explain what happens in 1st and 2nd point namely (0,1) and (0,0). Due to lack of writing skills i uploaded the entire question. Help me on this

Comment: The first point means that : $(x=0,y=1)$ which translates to $y(0)=1$. Using this to determine a constant, one yields : $$y(0) = 1 \Rightarrow 1=1$$ which is true for any value of the constant $c_1$, thus in this case, the constant is undetermined (can be any value $\in \mathbb R$). For the second case, we get : $y(0) = 0$. This, though, doesn't make much sense in the final form, as it would be $0=1$. I would try searching it up from the logarithmic form before handling the absolute values. It may be a wrong point though and that you just need to justify that it's impossible to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve it...

$$xy' = y^2- y$$
$$xy' +y= y^2$$
$$(xy)'= y^2$$
$$(xy)'= \frac {(xy)^2}{x^2}$$
$$\int \frac {d(xy)}{(xy)^2}= \int \frac {dx}{x^2}$$
$$ \frac {1}{(xy)}=  \frac {1}{x}+K$$
$$\boxed{y=\frac 1 {Kx+1}}$$